# Symfony Form data isn't sending with custom form image type theme

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, vichuploaderbundle, filepond

I am using a plugin called FilePond to have a better look while uploading an image with VichUploaderBundle. So to evoid the default form_row template of the bundle i made a custom one:

```
//template/forms/upload_image.html.twig
{% block _image_file_row %}
    <input type="file" class="filepond-initialise" name="image[file][file]" required="required" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png">
{% endblock %}
```

Then i render the template in the page:

```
{% form_theme form 'forms/upload_image.html.twig' %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.file) }}
    <h3>Tags</h3>
        <ul class="tags list-inline" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype.name)|e('html_attr') }}">
        {% for tag in form.tags %}
            <li>{{ form_row(tag.name) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Upload</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('image-upload') }}">
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

And this is the action in the controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request):Response
    {
        $image = new Image();
        $form = $this->createForm(ImageType::class, $image);
        $token = $request->request->get('token');
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $this->isCsrfTokenValid('image-upload', $token)) {
            dump($image);
            dump($form->getData());
            $this->em->persist($image);
            $this->em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_image_index');
        }

        return $this->render('admin/image/upload.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

The problem that the content of the file input doesn't seem to be sending in the form submit. i get an error of name property null:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO image (name, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, "2019-05-14 22:42:18"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null
```

and the dumping of the $image variable and $form-getData() as below:

```
Image {#496 ▼
  -id: null
  -file: null
  -name: null
  -updatedAt: DateTime @1557873995 {#497 ▼
    date: 2019-05-14 22:46:35.496026 UTC (+00:00)
  }
  -tags: ArrayCollection {#498 ▼
    -elements: array:3 [▼
      0 => Tag {#901 ▼
        -id: null
        -name: "sport"
        -images: ArrayCollection {#902 ▶}
      }
      1 => Tag {#878 ▼
        -id: null
        -name: "nature"
        -images: ArrayCollection {#905 ▶}
      }
      2 => Tag {#906 ▼
        -id: null
        -name: "fashion"
        -images: ArrayCollection {#908 ▶}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

While the tags inputs are working fine, means that the problem is with file input.

Here is the builder in ImageType.php the rest is by default :

```
$builder
            ->add('file', VichImageType::class)
            ->add('tags', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => TagType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
        ;
```

Comment: `name` field is required

Comment: As it's not possible to set the value of a file input element the file input will be empty. You either have to use the [file encode plugin](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/file-encode/) or have to upload the files asynchronously by using the `server` property.

Comment: I tried using the file encode plugin, but it still shows the same problem. and truth i don't want to use asynchronous method.

Comment: When i checked the profiler i found out that the file instance sent by the library is actually the homepage of my websilte. even though i didn't mention the server property. means the labrary is sending asynchronously by default.